# Why are ignored questions even showing?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I know that ignored questions are grayed out:

[image]

But why are they even showing up if I want to ignore them? This is anoying.

It would be much better if they were just hidden, then we could focus on the important questions without having to scroll past the grayed out questions first.

Comment: To answer the question in the title, because in some situations, users still want to moderate those questions, but not e.g. answering.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is already available.
Click on "edit" next to Favorite Tags on the right side of main page. Under the Ignore Tags section, there should be a toggle option to grey out the questions or hide them.

[image]

Just select on hide.